# I'm trying to populate the dropdown menu on the html form with the information on the Customer sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form that will populate the dropdown menu if I use the  code. I am wanting to populate the dropdown menu with the information on the "Customers" sheet.
The code below will populate the dropdown menu as I want, but then it doesn't transfer the name to the "Job" sheet. It will, however, transfer any text in the "Note" field as well as the hidden fields.

[QLF Jobs Sheet]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMADNpqCyKuuXKNHUaCc7u3kyW5WHRumgjwLrfXjbAs/edit?usp=sharing

```
**(Code.gs)**

function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getSelectList() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Customers");
    var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function processForm(formObject){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([formObject.key,
                    formObject.driver,
                    formObject.customer,
                    formObject.phone_Number,
                    formObject.note,
                    formObject.fill_Date,
                    formObject.history,
                    formObject.latLong,
                    formObject.color,
                    formObject.gallons,
                    formObject.lbs_Gal,
                    formObject.status,
  ]);
}
```

```
**(Index.html)**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  
  <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-8" style="background: bisque;">
<div id="output"></div>
<center>
<div>
<h1>-New QLF Order Form-</h1>
  
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                          
                                    <b><label for="customer">Customer Location(s)</label>
                                    <select id="customer">
                                    </select>
                                    <script>
                                      (function () {
                                        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                                          function (selectList) {
                                            var select = document.getElementById("customer");
                                            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
                                              var option = document.createElement("option");
                                              option.text = selectList[i][0];
                                              select.add(option);
                                            }
                                          }
                                        ).getSelectList();
                                      }());
                                    </script>
                        </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <b><label for="note">Note</label></b>
                                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="note" name="note" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                                    
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="status"></label>
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" value="Pending">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="order_added"></label>
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="order_added" name="order_added" value="New Order">
                            </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block">Submit</button>

                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
**(JavaScript)**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

  function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}


</script>
  </body>
</html>
``
```